# Multiple "If" answers in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to make a fishing tournament spreadsheet.... I would like to perform in once cell that if their position was first, they get 100 points.  if their position is second, they get 90 points, if they get third, they get 80... And so on down to 10... Is this possible to get an "IF" statement that would calculate the points automatically by just punching in a 1-10 number?

if c2=1 then d2=100
if c2=2 then d2=90
if c2=3 then d2=80

and so on

Comment: If you have the ranking of each fisherman in a column through their entries, it is easy to compute the points in an adjacent column.

It would also be good to sort them by whatever it is that determines those rankings though.  Then you can deal with ties.  Are ties not possible?

Also, I assume if there are more than 9 rankings, all of the lower finishers after the 9th (without duplicates) get 0, yes?  Or is the size of the tournament limited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this more flexible (e.g. with 125, 100, ..., 45, 40 as you indicated in a comment), it is better to have a "scores" table somewhere that has rank in the first column and score in the second, e.g.:

```
  A      B
╔══════╦═══════╗
║ Rank ║ Score ║
╠══════╬═══════╣
║ 1    ║ 125   ║
║ 2    ║ 100   ║
║ 3    ║ 75    ║
║ 4    ║ 50    ║
║ 5    ║ 45    ║
║ 6    ║ 40    ║
║ ...  ║       ║
╚══════╩═══════╝
```

Then you can determine the score for a rank with the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,Scores!$A:$B,2,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Formula for d2:

```
=100-((c2-1)*10)
```

Copy this down the list (ie from d2 down to d11) and it will give correct points in column D

If you want to adjust the amount of points you award for first place, simply change the 100 at the front of the formula into whatever the maximum score is, and you're good to go.

This works because the difference between places (eg 2nd and 3rd) is always 10.  If those numbers change (eg 2nd to 3rd is 10pts difference, 3rd to 4th is 20pts difference) it becomes harder to alter.

For your comment example, you'd have to change the formula in D2 to something like:

```
=if(c2<5, 125-((c2-1)*250), 50-((c2-5)*5))
```

Comment: Say I wanted to make first 125 points... second 100, third 75, fourth 50... fifth 45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20..  How much more difficult does that make it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use multiple IF statements. The following will suffice:

```
=IF(position>0,MAX(100-(position-1)*10,0),0)
```

where *position* is the cell containing the angler's position.

Comment: =IF(D2>0,MAX(100-(C2-4)*10,0),0)  is this what it would look like?  if so, i keep getting error508

Comment: I wish that worked... But I am not very well versed in excel... And its not working

Comment: I don't understand the use of an IF.  If the positions are in column C and you want to put the points in column D, for the fisherman whose information is in row j, the formula is simply =MAX(100-(Dj-1)*10;0).  An OpenOffice error508 probably means Dj doesn't have a number in it.

Comment: @orcmid, I had a cut/paste error in my post (fixed now). You're correct, the IF is intended to verify the angler has a valid position (>0).